# OpenLayers marker's popups with ctrl behavior

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a question about OpenLayers.Marker events. 
I want to have a map with few markers and popups. By default - clicking on marker shows popup. Clicking on any other marker hides prevous popup and shows new one.
That works fine with:

```
marker.events.register('click', marker, function(e){
                   var  popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("Popup",
                                new OpenLayers.LonLat(val.longitude,val.latitude).transform(
                                    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                                    map.getProjectionObject()),
                                null,
                                '<div>Hello World! Put your html here</div>',
                                null,
                                true);
                    map.addPopup(popup, **true**);
```

What if I want to click more than one marker and show all marker's popups using CTRL key (behavior like map.addPopup(popup, **false**))? I have no idea how to do it. :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you want to achieve this: when Ctrl is down and user selects Marker, all currently opened popups will remain opened; and when Marker is selected without Ctrl key, all other popups will be closed?

Following things pops into mind: at first, keep track, whether Ctrl key is down or not (to my knowledge, there is no other way than to listen for keydown and keyup events):

```
var ctrlIsDown = false;

$(window).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.ctrlKey)
        ctrlIsDown = true;
});

$(window).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.ctrlKey)
        ctrlIsDown = false;
});
```

And when adding popup to map, just check state of control key:

```
if (ctrlIsDown)
    map.addPopup(popup, false);
else
    map.addPopup(popup, true);
```